# ClassNotFoundException when trying to start a Service from an Activity in Android

Tags: android, exception, service

I'm trying to start a service from my activity like this:

```
startService(new Intent(MyActivity.this,
                MyService.class));
```

There is a problem however. Nothing happens. I debugged behind the scenes and I can see that the BootClassLoader trips up on a ClassNotFoundException. I don't know how can that happen because I got my Service class in my manifest file like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:enabled="true">
        <service android:name=".MyService" android:exported="false"></service>
        ...
    </application>
```

and it is in the same package as MyActivity. I'm a little nuts here. What can be the problem? I debugged into MyService but `onCreate()`  and `onStartCommand()` does not get called either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea: if you go to "bin" folder of the project there should be your "*.apk" file. Rename it to zip, unzip and investigate if there is your service class. I suspect smth went wrong at build step and your class is not in the apk. Delete everything that is in bin folder and manage to rebuild the project from scratch. Then unzip/check again.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem....well I called adb uninstall too just to make sure that the buggy code got wiped from my droids.

Answer (score 3):

This kinda crap just happens sometimes. Try cleaning the project...

Also, if you're starting the service from a different package, try using the full package and then class name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.example.Something", "com.example.Something.MyService");
startService(intent);
```

Comment: I already tried that. I even restarted Eclipse and my phone. I tried it on my other phone too but it keeps throwing that Exception...

Answer (score 0):

Is the service in some package? if so, you may need to use the full path of the Service class in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

If you still have a problem, in the Manifest.XML file tack on the package name to the beginning of the service name as follows:

```
<service android:name="mypackagename.MyService"></service>
```

Not sure why you have that "exported" code in there.