# In Android, is there a way to check if a certain service exists?

Tags: java, android, exception, service

When calling `startActivity`, one can try to catch an `ActivityNotFoundException` to know whether the activity exists.

When calling `startService`, however, there is no `ServiceNotFoundException`. How can I detect if the service exists?

**Why do I want to do this**

As I have learnt, a call to `startService` will be processed asynchronously, hence I would like to know whether I should expect a response (e.g. a callback, or a broadcast) from the service or not.

**What have I done so far**

I searched a bit and find a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8128458/3250971). It seems that internally there is a `ClassNotFoundException` raised.

Is it possible to catch this exception somewhere? The `Class.forName()` method doesn't seem right ... or is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is your own service, you know whether your service exists. This issue only comes into play if you are trying to work with some third-party service. In that case, use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentServices()` to see if there is something that matches your `Intent`.

For example, in this sample app, I use `queryIntentServices()` to:

- Confirm that there is only one match for my `Intent`
- Convert it from an implicit `Intent` to an explicit `Intent`
- Validate the signing key of the service, so that I know that it is not some service that is masquerading as the one I want to work with (e.g., repackaged app with malware)

Mostly, that is handled in `onCreate()` of the client fragment that will bind to the service:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);

    appContext=(Application)getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    Intent implicit=new Intent(IDownload.class.getName());
    List<ResolveInfo> matches=getActivity().getPackageManager()
      .queryIntentServices(implicit, 0);

    if (matches.size() == 0) {
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot find a matching service!",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (matches.size() > 1) {
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Found multiple matching services!",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
      ServiceInfo svcInfo=matches.get(0).serviceInfo;

      try {
        String otherHash=SignatureUtils.getSignatureHash(getActivity(),
          svcInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
        String expected=getActivity().getString(R.string.expected_sig_hash);

        if (expected.equals(otherHash)) {
          Intent explicit=new Intent(implicit);
          ComponentName cn=new ComponentName(svcInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
            svcInfo.name);

          explicit.setComponent(cn);
          appContext.bindService(explicit, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
        else {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unexpected signature found!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception trying to get signature hash", e);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This looks exactly what I want. I will test it later.