# Explicit and Implicit intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm a bit confused on **Intents**.

Why is

```
Intent implicit=new Intent(IDownload.class.getName());
```

an *Implicit intent*

while

```
Intent explicit=new Intent(implicit);
```

is an *Explicit intent* while it doesn't seem to add anything new in its definition. The system doesn't seem to draw any new information that wasn't previously provided by `implicit` intent above?

In the [Android documentation (Intent types)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Types),

> Explicit intents specify the component to start by name (the fully-qualified class name). You'll typically use an explicit intent to start a component in your own app, because you know the class name of the activity or service you want to start......

`Intent implicit=new Intent(IDownload.class.getName());` seems to fulfill this requirement, but is still regarded as an Implicit intent, which as per the documentation:

> Implicit intents do not name a specific component, but instead declare a general action to perform, which allows a component from another app to handle it.....

`Intent explicit=new Intent(implicit);` seems to contradict this, but is still regarded as an Explicit intent.

**UPDATE - Sample implementation**

ref : [Binding to a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37907805/3663765)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setRetainInstance(true);

  appContext=(Application)getActivity().getApplicationContext();

  Intent implicit=new Intent(IDownload.class.getName());
  List<ResolveInfo> matches=getActivity().getPackageManager()
  .queryIntentServices(implicit, 0);

  if (matches.size() == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot find a matching service!",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  else if (matches.size() > 1) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Found multiple matching services!",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  else {
    ServiceInfo svcInfo=matches.get(0).serviceInfo;

    try {
      String otherHash=SignatureUtils.getSignatureHash(getActivity(),
        svcInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
      String expected=getActivity().getString(R.string.expected_sig_hash);

      if (expected.equals(otherHash)) {
        Intent explicit=new Intent(implicit);
        ComponentName cn=new ComponentName(svcInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
          svcInfo.name);

        explicit.setComponent(cn);
        appContext.bindService(explicit, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
      }
      else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unexpected signature found!",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception trying to get signature hash", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What makes you say that `Intent explicit=new Intent(implicit);` is an explicit intent?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37907805/3663765 @BenP.

Comment: In that example, the Intent is still an implicit intent until he calls `explicit.setComponent(cn)`. It is the setting of the component name that makes the intent explicit; he's just naming the variable `explicit` because _in a few lines_ it will be.

Comment: The handling component is set in the following code, and that make the Intent explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked example includes these lines

```
      Intent explicit=new Intent(implicit);
      ComponentName cn=new ComponentName(svcInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
        svcInfo.name);

      explicit.setComponent(cn);
```

The first line simply creates a new `Intent` instance that's a copy of the old one. While the variable might be `explicit`, at this point in time, it is still an implicit intent.

The second line creates a `ComponentName` object based on the single matching result from an earlier `getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(implicit, 0)` call. At this point, `explicit` is still an implicit intent.

The third line is the magic. Once the specific `ComponentName` is assigned to the `Intent` instance, `explicit` truly becomes an explicit intent.

Comment: `IDownload.class.getName()` doesn't this qualify as a fully-qualified class name - [Android documentation (Intent types)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Types)?

Comment: `Class.getName()` returns a `String`, which means you're using the `Intent(String)` constructor. In this case, the string is the "action", which is **not** a "fully-qualified class name". You'd need to use the `Intent(Context, Class)` or `Intent(String, Uri, Context, Class)` constructors.